# Is <span> containing multiple <td>s legitimate?

Tags: html

To wit:

```
<table><tr><span><td>Hi</td><td>Again</td></span></tr></table>
```

Is this legitimate HTML?

Comment: Did you check? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: put the spans in the TDs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; `<tr>`s can only contain `<td>`s and `<th>`s.